# How can I get selected value in combobox?

Tags: java, combobox, save

I can show coursename in combobox but  I want to save courseId when I select course name.
How can I do that? I am using hibernate, SQL and Java.

```
public void coursename(){
  Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
  session.beginTransaction();
  Query query= session.createQuery("select a.courseName  from Semester e inner join e.course as a"); 
  for (Iterator it = query.iterate(); it.hasNext();) {
    Object  row = (Object) it.next();
    combocourse.addItem(row);
    System.out.println(row);

  }        
  session.close();
}
```

Comment: add an ItemListener to you combobox and in the itemStateChanged method invoke a hibernate save.

Answer (score 0):

Store an object in your combobox that includes the name and the ID. Ensure the name is returned in the `toString()` method:

```
public class Course {
  private final String name;
  private final int id;

  // ...

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return name;
  }
}
```

Then you can retrieve the selected object and obtain the ID value. You will need to use a `JComboBox<Course>` combobox (assuming you are using Swing).